# python - tensorflow execution on Ubuntu server with CUDA GeForce9600GT

Tags: python, ubuntu, cuda, tensorflow

I just went through the [cifar10 tensorflow tutorial](http://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.md) on my mac. This tutorial aroused my enthusiasm for NN so I set a Ubuntu Server up in order to train in large scale.

However I cant run the cifar10_train.py on my server. I always run into this error:

Path of the tensorflow source code:

```
~/python/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/
```

Path of the tensorflow virtualenv installation:

```
~/tensorflow/
```

**Cmd:**

```
source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate #activate virtualenv
python/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_train.py #the raw source code of tensorflow is in ~/python/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_train.py", line 28, in <module>
    import tensorflow.python.platform
  File "/home/it13095/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/it13095/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.client.client_lib import *
  File "/home/it13095/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/client_lib.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.client.session import InteractiveSession
  File "/home/it13095/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 11, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as tf_session
  File "/home/it13095/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/it13095/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
```

I installed tensorflow just like on my mac in a virtualenv and activated it correctly before executing the script. 
As by many in other threads suggested I upgraded already six, however I still got the same error.

**Update 1**
After going the issue threads on github/tensorflow through I noticed this is a bug involving cuda. I added these to my path environment:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64"
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
```

I still run into a error, however it has shortened down to the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cifar10_train.py", line 28, in <module>
import tensorflow.python.platform
ImportError: No module named tensorflow.python.platform
```

**Update 2** As someone suggested, I install protobuf via pip. The Error has once again change for some weird reason:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cifar10_train.py", line 28, in <module>
    import tensorflow.python.platform
  File "/home/it13095/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/it13095/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "/home/it13095/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import attr_value_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_attr__value__pb2
  File "/home/it13095/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/attr_value_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__pb2
  File "/home/it13095/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_shape_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__shape__pb2
  File "/home/it13095/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape_pb2.py", line 22, in <module>
    serialized_pb=_b('\n,tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.proto\x12\ntensorflow\"d\n\x10TensorShapeProto\x12-\n\x03\x64im\x18\x02 \x03(\x0b\x32 .tensorflow.TensorShapeProto.Dim\x1a!\n\x03\x44im\x12\x0c\n\x04size\x18\x01 \x01(\x03\x12\x0c\n\x04name\x18\x02 \x01(\tb\x06proto3')
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'syntax'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TensorFlow currently requires CUDA toolkit 7.0 and cuDNN.

cuDNN requires a cc 3.0 GPU, and CUDA toolkit 7.0 requires a cc 2.0 GPU.

Your 9600GT does not satisfy these [requirements](http://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup.md):

> In order to build or run TensorFlow with GPU support, both Cuda Toolkit 7.0 and CUDNN 6.5 V2 from NVIDIA need to be installed.
>
> TensorFlow GPU support requires having a GPU card with NVidia Compute Capability >= 3.5.

So if you want to use TensorFlow with GPU support, you will need a cc3.5 or higher GPU, and follow the steps to install the needed support software correctly.  Alternatively, you could install TensorFlow without GPU support.